# How to handle SEO for client components in Next.js 13?

Tags: next.js, seo, server-side-rendering

I'm confused on how to manage SEO for client components in Next.js 13.

Let's say I want to create a contact us page at `/contact`

In the new framework, I should create a folder named `contact` inside the `app` directory. And in it I should create a page called `page.js` by convention.

Now I need to create a form, which of course needs to manage its state. Thus I should use `useState` or other hooks from react.

But when I do that, Next.js compiler complains that it's a server component and if I want to use it on the client-side, I should mark it with `'use client'` directive at the top.

But I don't want the component to be rendered on the client-side. I need my `/contact` page to be indexed by search engines.

What should I do?

Comment: [Client components](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components#client-components) are still pre-rendered on the server. But unlike server components, they also get hydrated on the client. As long as your SEO logic is not being handled in client-side only code (inside `useEffect`), there shouldn't be any issue.

Answer (score 9):

`use client` does not mean that your component will be rendered on client only.

It works as previous versions of Next.js.

It will be rendered on server and hydrated on client.

Comment: THIS is extremely unclear in the next documentation, while is extremely clear in other frameworks like Astro. It's a huge hole that generate a lot of confusion. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use hooks on server components. Server components are rendered on the server side, and thus can't hold state like client-components. Try moving the form into a new, client-side component, and render that from the `/contact`-page

**page.js**

```
const ContactPage = () => {
  // set your SEO headers etc here
  return (
    <CustomForm />
  )
}
```

**CustomForm.jsx**

```
'use client'
const CustomForm = () => {
  // Handle your state and form rendering in this component
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. But it seems that you have not understood my problem correctly. I'm talking about rendering client-components on the server, because of SEO.

Comment: You can't render state-based things on server side. Render SEO critical stuff on server, and state based stuff on client side

Comment: Added example, take a look and see if it helps

Comment: Server components != client components...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [next-seo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-seo) npm package. you can find the examples for normal pages.

for `app` directory usage [read the docs](https://github.com/garmeeh/next-seo/blob/HEAD/APP_DIRECTORY.md)

> Key Changes
>
> Next.js no longer de-duplicates tags in the head. This means that we
> can no longer use  in the same way. Going forward we
> will solely be use `<NextSeo />`

> head.js does not currently support  tags that do no have src="". So for JSON-LD components they
> now have to be added via the page. This will result in them being
> added to the  of the page. This is 100% ok for SEO and not to
> worry about. This was confirmed by Google. I have also validated this
> using schema tool.

> Next.js no longer auto adds the tags below to your
> app that you will likely need. I suggest adding them to your root
> layout in a  tag.

Answer (score 0):

As *Sefa Kocaaga* answered, it works similarly to previous versions. It is rendered on the server side and hydrated on the client side. You can read about it here.

https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#client-components